# How to know from in app that update for same app is available

Tags: android, google-play, updates

we usually see when we launch a specific app sometimes it automatically prompts that an update is available for this app.. update now.

I want this feature in my app also.

i just want to know method or how does the app communicates with play store to know that update is available.

thank you

Comment: The app should ping its server to get some value always on app initializing based on that value you can identify that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use android-query for querying the current version name of your application.

It will give you a result like : https://androidquery.appspot.com/api/market?app=com.google.android.youtube (example for Youtube)

Then, in your code, compare the version in the result with the current version name of your application.